# Remap Alt+Tab function

Tags: autohotkey

My keyboard tab key is not working. How I will remap the functionality of alt+tab to alt+capslock ? And without making capslock to goes on and off when capslock key is pressed while holding alt key.

the 1 key(not in the numpad) is also broken. How I will make to alt+2 = 1 and alt+shift+2 = exclamation(!)

PS: I don't have knowledge in autohotkey yet. I just want to remap those broken keys. Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, I would personally suggest learning autohotkey, might take 4 maybe even 5 minutes to learn how to do what you want to do using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this autohotkey script should do what you want:

```
!Capslock::!Tab ; map alt+Capslock to alt+Tab  
!2::send 1  ; map alt+2 to 1  
!+2::sendraw !  ; map alt+shift+2 to !
```

Comment: Thank you :). I tried !Shift::Tab to remap the tab function to alt+shift but it works as alt+Tab. How will I remap the tab function(tabbing in textbox) ?

Comment: I suggest you map CTLR+Capslock to TAB, the script would be:
^Capslock::Tab